# почему я вижу undefined, а не true?

Tags: javascript

Я хочу отобразить сообщение в методе «toString» о статусе персонажа true или false, в зависимости от его здоровья

```js
function Character() {
        this.health = 100;
        this.basicDamage = 10;
        this.toString = function () {
            return this.name + this.status; // the properties that I want to reflect
        }
    }
Character.createArcher = function () {
    var hero = new Character;
    hero.name = "Legolas"; // set hero name
    return hero;
};
Character.isAlive = function () {
    var hp = new Character;
 if (this.health > 0){
     hp.status = true;
 }else if (this.health <= 0){
     hp.status = false;
 }else {
     alert("ERROR");
 }
 return hp;
};
var archer = new Character.createArcher();
console.log(archer.toString());
```

Comment: все верно, ты создаешь в локальном скоупе переменную var hero, вместо this.hero, и соответственно toString выдает пустосту
думаю та же проблема будет в методе isAlive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У только что созданного персонажа свойство `status` не инициализировано. Вернее, этого свойства у объекта просто нет.

```
function Character() {
  this.status = "just_born";
  this.health = 100;
  ...
```